# Conversion in sql Power Cast

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to do a small query to convert a string :

Doing this query here:-

```
 Select (120 * POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 32) + 87) As Test
```

will give me the result of :

```
 515396075607
```

Now, I want to convert the `"515396075607"` into a query and the result should give me 120..
Its like back and forth... like **Inch -> CM** / **CM -> Inch**

Any thought?

Comment: Are you trying to write your own encryption? [it's not a a good idea](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) - if not, what are 120 and 87?

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of the function is:

```
select exp(log(2) * (log(515396075607 - 87)/log(2) - 32))
```

This would more easily be expressed as:

```
select exp2(log2(515396075607 - 87) - 32)
```

However, not all versions of SQL Server allow you to provide the base for logs and exponents.